# NLog File Target:App launch from file share, write to C:\Temp - No output

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, nlog

I'm using a file target to write to a log file like so:

```
fileName="/Temp/Logs/AppDir/App.log"
```

When the application is on the local drive it works fine and writes to this location. If I move the application to a file share then I don't get a log file in this location and no errors.

I assume it's permissions. Can you not write to the local drive at all in this case or just temp? Can I have it write elsewhere or is there some setting in the NLog config or something I need to look at?

Section of code from program.cs: Note that I am not seeing the message box in the catch and the application is running normally:

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        Logger.Info("Application Start");
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var settings = new Settings();

        if (settings.AccessDenied)
            Application.Run(new FormAccessDenied());
        else
            Application.Run(new FormMain(settings));
    }
    catch (CommunicationException ce)
    {
        Logger.Error($"{ce.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{ce.StackTrace}");
        MessageBox.Show($"{ce.Message}{Environment.NewLine}The application can not proceed");
    }
    catch (Exception up)
    {
        Logger.Error($"{up.Message}{Environment.NewLine}{up.StackTrace}");
        MessageBox.Show($"An error has occurred in the application. Please consult the log file for more information");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: add some logging to your code and see if you are getting a `Access Denied` error.. this sounds like a permissions issue. also it would help if we can see what your code is doing currently

Comment: At a min it will log that it started up. It's not even creating the file. I'm not sure what logging code I would add since this is the logging code.

Comment: are you familiar with `try{}catch()` and use the Exception that deals with System.IO Errors.. just post your code and we can help otherwise you are expecting many answers based on speculation / guessing.

Comment: I am yes. Thanks.

Comment: then post the portion of code where you are writing to the network share.. also read the `faq on HOW TO ASK A QUESTION`

Comment: edit your code and paste your code there.. not in the comments section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a permission error. You could check that by:

or: enable internal logging, in your config, in this case warn is enough

```
<nlog internalLogFile="c:\log.txt" internalLogLevel="Warn">
```

or, enable exception throwing.

```
<nlog throwExceptions="true" />
```

It's recommend to turn of `throwExceptions` in production (the default)

Comment: This was not the exact answer but it lead me there. Instead of having a relative path I needed absolute like in the internalLogFile you have up there. I updated both target fileName and archiveFileName to use c:\temp\... and I'm getting a log file now.